# Arrange sqllite table data in tabular form in android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, tabular

I am trying to display table data in tabular form in android program.

My table:

```
orderno   productid   productqty   custid
1         1000001      2            00010
2         1000001      5            00010
```

I want display that table in the android front end. For that I write the following program:

```
 dbadapter.open();
 Cursor cursor=dbadapter.fetchordersdata(custid);
 int count=cursor.getCount();
```

From this I am getting the table data. How can I arrange this data in tabular form?

Comment: even googling a little may help you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

get data from database and append data to string and load this str to web view follow this code

```
String mStr="";

mStr=mStr.concat("<body >");
mStr=mStr.concat("<tr><td align='center'><b>orderno</b></td><td align='center'><b>productid</b></td><td align='center'><b>productqty</b></td>
<td align='center'><b>custid</b></td></tr>");

dbadapter.open();
Cursor cursor=dbadapter.fetchordersdata(custid);
cursor.moveToFirst();
while(!cursor.isAfterLast())
            {
mStr=mStr.concat("<tr><td>"+(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("col1")))+"</td><td>"+(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("col2")))+"</td>
<td>"+(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("col3")))+"</td>
<td>"+(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("col4")))+"</td></tr>");


  cursor.moveToNext();
}

   mStr.concat("</table></body>");
```

i hope this code will help u...
WebView web =(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
web.loadData(mStr,"text/html",null);

Answer (score 0):

On the XML side: create a table view.

On the src side: create an object (called Data Access Object) that is responsible for connecting with the DB, retrieving the data you need and putting that information inside your table view.

Comment: <TableLayout
android:id="@+id/rows_table"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
android:padding="10dp"
android:background="color or drawable"
android:shrinkColumns="*"  
android:stretchColumns="*"/>

Comment: i created this how can i append dynamic values to this i am getting the data from table also ?